# What's the deal with these mysterious Ingredient items?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

When I'm grinding away in dungeons, I sometimes pick up these items shaped like mushrooms, labeled with a giant question mark and the name "Ingredient". These end up taking up a lot of space in my preciously small loot bag, and as far as I can tell I don't end up actually taking them back with me when the dungeon ends. My best guess is that these are items that I can't identify until either my Merchant or Adventurer level is high enough. Am I correct? Was this something explained in the tutorial that I kind of glossed over...? :(

What are these Ingredient items?

Comment: Yup. Explained in the tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, it's tied to your merchant level, so you can't tell what they are until it gets higher.

HOWEVER, when you leave the dungeon they automatically get identified, so you can look later and see what you found. The only real downside is that you can't know if it's good or worthless while you're deciding what to keep in the dungeon.

Comment: If I identify an ingredient as a result of leaving the dungeon, will that ingredient remain identified on all future trips to dungeons?

Comment: @mana To my knowledge, no. Additionally, I *think* an already identified item (say, a slime drop) can even be 'unidentified' if it's got a +5 (so Slime Drop +5 vs. Slime Drop).